# Postman gets a valid token but getting 401 from API

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to test my ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API with Postman. My API is protected by Azure AD. I have been using the "Web App your API" Microsoft Azure [Sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API) and triple-checked all of the steps.

Using Postman I ask it to get a token using the OAuth2 Implicit flow and I do get a token returned. If I decode the token it seems to contain all the claims I want: `aud`, `upn` and `scp` all make sense.

However, when I then send a request to the API using the returned token I still get a 401.

The API is working because if I remove the `[Authorize]` attribute I get data returned.

If I try accessing the API with a web client I get an error: `MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.` but that makes no sense given that my `upn` is returned in the token.

Can anyone recommend further action to figure out what's wrong.

#### UPDATE

On [line 381 of TokenAcquisition.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/faa94fd49c2da46b22d6694c4f5c5895795af26d/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenAcquisition.cs#L381) `account` is `null` so when `AcquireTokenSilent()` is subsequently called the result is `null`.

Comment: No super specific recommendation - sounds like something you have to work through - but usually when I run into issues like this I end up having to tear it down and start with what I know works and gradually introduce new elements until I find the problem.

Comment: 401 means the access token is not correct. What is the detailed error message?

Comment: Also show your implicit flow request with postman

Comment: Yeah I'm on the long path of incremental building again. No other text than 401. Nan Yu, not sure what you're asking. You mean the request and response details?

Comment: Yes. Please add an update about the request of how you get the token and use the token in Postman.

Comment: @NanYu Are you sure that a 401 means the access token is incorrect? You do not get issued an access token if the authentication is incorrect. Perhaps it is an authorization issue.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned Postman for a while and focused on a web client. I had to rename my `Application ID URI` in the Azure Portal from `https://<company>.onmircrosoft.com/<myapi>/user_impersonation` to `api://<application_guid>/access_as_user` and similarly in my application code. This made TokenAcquisition.cs start returning a token and I got the Web App talking to the API.

I still don't have Postman working though now it returns a message: `invalid_client`. Probably as I need to use a different flow. Anyhow, I'm happy for the moment.