# Postman returns 401 despite the valid token distributed for a secure endpoint

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I've set up the authorization like this, loosely following the three blogs [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api), [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/16/aspnet-core-3-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api) and [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/21/aspnet-core-3-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) (basically making it wide open except for the validation of the expiration time).

```
string secret = "super-secret-password";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(bytes);
TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  IssuerSigningKey = key,
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
  ValidateIssuer = false,
  ValidateAudience = false,
  RequireAudience = false,
  RequireExpirationTime = false,
  RequireSignedTokens = false
};
services.AddAuthentication(_ => _.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(_ => _.TokenValidationParameters = parameters);
```

The token distributed is created like this.

```
string secret = "super-secret-password";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(bytes);

Claim[] claims = {
  new Claim("role", "basic"),
  new Claim("role", "elevated"),
  new Claim("name", name)
};

JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
  Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
  Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
  SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};

SecurityToken token = handler.CreateToken(descriptor);
return handler.WriteToken(token);
```

Then, I paste the returned string into JWT.io and it confirms that everything is great (valid signature and all that). However, when I use that token in Postman (it adds the header *Bearer + my_token_string*), the call gives me 401 unauthorized.

I tried two secure methods in my controller and one open (the latter works as expected).

```
[HttpGet("open"), AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult OpenResult() { return Ok("Open result accessed."); }
[HttpGet("secure"), Authorize]
public ActionResult SecureResult() { return Ok("Secure result accessed."); }
[HttpGet("elevated"), Authorize(Roles = "elevated")]
public ActionResult ElevatedResult() { return Ok("Elevated result accessed."); }
```

I don't know what I might be missing. Even worse, I'm not sure how to investigate it further.

**What can I do at this point?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225245/postman-returning-with-401-unothorized-when-valid-token-is-passed-while-working) suggest setting headers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978358/postman-gets-a-valid-token-but-getting-401-from-api) is irrelevant for my relaxed case with no validation of audience. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503362/resttemplate-returns-401-while-postman-succeeds) gives nothing much, really. (Just making sure to show that I've done my effort.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to check is the ordering of "use" statements in Configure in Startup.cs.  If you have app.UseAuthorization() before app.UseAuthentication() you'll get 401s.  This has caught me before:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication(); //make sure this comes before app.UseAuthorization()
        app.UseAuthorization(); 
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHubService>("/notification");
        });
    }
```